# how to append results of a function in a for loop that are variable in length

Tags: r

Applying a function in a for loop gives a vector of results that are variable in length every time (for example the first iteration might give 4 numbers the 2nd might give 10 numbers etc) How can you apply a function in a for loop and save every iteration without using external to R packages?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `lapply` is designed for. Same effect as Mael's answer but in a single line.

```r
lapply(seq(10), numeric)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0 0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[10]]
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I know you were looking for only base packages, but `purrr::map` also does this.

```r
purrr::map(seq(10), numeric)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0 0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[10]]
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

There is `Map` in base R, but I personally don't like it because the function comes first making it less "pipeable"

```
Map(numeric, seq(10))
```